# Debugging (.NET) docker containers on Apple M1 (Silicon)

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio-code, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am currently trying to attach to a Docker container with my Visual Studio Code on an Apple machine with M1 pro processor.

I have managed to successfully attach the container and I am able to debug IF there are no errors. The moment an exception is hit, the container exits with code 137. There is no information on the container why it exited and OOMKill is false.

My Docker Engine has 10GB allocated so I do not think that RAM memory is the issue.

Used base image: `--platform=linux/arm64/v8 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-focal-arm64v8`.

The VS Code & Docker Engine are the latest for Apple M1.

I am not sure what the issue is and why the container just exits. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the 137 error code was deceiving. VS Code was actually throwing a 139 OOM Killed error. Even though the container did not exit with OOMKilled and OOMKilled is still false, I upped the resources on the containers themselves.

Update: It only fixes the issue when simple exceptions are thrown (e.g object is null). I still cannot debug foreach statements or Mappings from IMapper.